# PHP substr - extract numbers from string

Tags: php, substr

I need to extract the highlighted numbers from each line in a CSV file.

Currently I am looping though the lines & splitting the line on the / character as this only appears once in each row, but how do I remove everything around these numbers so I am left with:

9/10

10/11

11/12

...

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try [`fgetcsv()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) with `~` as the delimiter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to only get the numbers, you could do a [preg_match](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$re = '/(\d+\/\d+)/s';
$str = 'dfsadsfadsfads~~9/10~~lfkjdskfds';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

but if you are able to get the entire doc as a single string, you could do a [preg_match_all](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$re = '/(\d+\/\d+)/s';
$str = 'dfsadsfadsfads~~9/10~~lfkjdskfds\ndfsadsfadsfads~~9/10~~lfkjdskfds\n';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

then loop on the $matches

Comment: Thanks, but seems to be stripping the left number to a single digit
9/10
0/11
1/12
3/14
- Also these numbers can be much larger than double digits

Comment: I would just add that you don't really need the `m` flag here.  It's only relevant to the start and end of a string such as the use of `^` or `$`.  Basically it changes those so they match the start and end of a line, instead of the whole string (the default behavior).  It doesn't hurt anything to have it, just thought I would mention it.  Otherwise, it's what I would have done.

Comment: @kb I fixed the left number issue by adding a + symbol to the regex. Should work like needed.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I removed the m flag as suggested

Comment: @rtrigoso - Kool, I already upvoted you so I would do it again but alas I cant :)

Comment: @kb. If you could provide a sample string of the data, I'm sure it can be fine tuned.